# Ambiguous method overloading for method com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder#

Tags: groovy, soapui

When I tried this groovy script in SoapUI 5.5.0 I get this error:

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder# . Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between: [interface org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject] [interface org.w3c.dom.Node] error at line: 19

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

log.info "welcome to canada"

def name=context.expand ('${#TestCase#name}')

log.info context.expand ('${#TestSuite#place}')
//log.info context.expand('${#AddAutomation#id}')//its not going to grab values or properties of other testcases 
def id=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["AddAutomation"].getPropertyValue("id")

def age=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("age","23")
def department=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["AddAutomation"].setPropertyValue("department","CSE")

def request=log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["AddAutomation"].testSteps["Add"].getPropertyValue("Request")

def xmlnew=new XmlHolder(request)
xmlnew.setNodeValue("\\typ:addEmployee\typ:name","name")

xmlnew.setNodeValue("\\typ:addEmployee\typ:id","id")

xmlnew.setNodeValue("\\typ:addEmployee\typ:age","age")
xmlnew.setNodevalue("\\typ:addEmployee\typ:department","department")
```

Comment: I'd guess, that `request` is null - if this is intended, then you have to cast request

Answer (score 0):

Your script has:

```
...
def request=log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["AddAutomation"].testSteps["Add"].getPropertyValue("Request")

def xmlnew=new XmlHolder(request)
...
```

The line `log.info` will always return `null`, so the next line errors. In all likelihood what you actually want is:

```
...
def request=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["AddAutomation"].testSteps["Add"].getPropertyValue("Request")
log.info request
def xmlnew=new XmlHolder(request)
...
```